# vs 2019 can't find local db. error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019

I am creating a cloud service(MVC and WCF)in Visual Studio 2019 with a db in SSMS, local on my machine. I am using Entity Framework Code First. I've been stuck for a long time on getting my code to 'ReadAll' from my db. The issues I'm facing seem to be with the connection string and/or the DBcontext. But what gets me is that the connection string is fine for scaffolding the db tables.

When I have my DBContext Constructor as this:

```
public partial class Model5 : DbContext
{
    public Model5()
        : base("name=Model5")
    {
    }
```

Then I get this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No connection string named 'Model5' could be found in the application config file.'

When I have my DBContext Constructor as this:

```
public partial class Model5 : DbContext
{
    public Model5()
        : base("Model5")
    {
    }
```

Then I get this error:
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: 'An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. '

SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
)

Here is my connection string (located in the app config file of the class library). Like I said, this connection string is fine for creating the tables using Entity Framework CodeFirst, but not for 'ReadAll' function.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model5" 
         connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=TradingPlatform4;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: "." is commonly used for SQL Express and would be used with an instance name. I.e. ".\SQLExpress". `(localdb)` is commonly used with SQL Server instances. You database server may have an instance name that needs to be specified within the connection string.

Comment: SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is not a database server, it's a client. Not unlike Outlook is a client for mail servers. Do you have an instance of SQL Server installed somewhere?

Comment: I have solved this...with a cloud service it is necessary to have the connection string in the MVC and WCF service part, in the web config, as well as the class library

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to the local database, you could try to change your connection string to this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model5" 
        connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=TradingPlatform4;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```